# Magento Free extension for backup and restore content?

Tags: magento-1.9

i have installed Backup Guard of version 1.0.4 extension but it is not working at the time of import can any one suggest Magento1.9.2 Free extension for backup and restore content ?

Comment: don't you want you to use Default magento backup under `system > Tools > Backup`

Comment: but with that how would I restore it ??

Comment: you can see at the end " Rollback" button http://prnt.sc/b4nsoa once you click there it will rollback to the state when you took the backup. you can take both files , images & database backup using this procedure, you can try in demo site once. but if you have thousands of products it will take much time to take backup & rollback.

Comment: sorry i mean to say if i have a backup of another setup how could i import that one in my setup of magento

Comment: if i understood correctly, you can copy the files and database manually to required setup.

Comment: I took the backup file of a setup and put it in var/backups of my setup but it doesn't shows in the backup lists from system > Tools > Backup so how could i rollback it

Comment: Did you took the backup by clicking on "system backup" button ?

Comment: yeah.. from that system backup

Comment: Seems there is some problem , is var folder is having writabale permission ? can you try for database backup ?

Comment: let me check it first and let u know

Comment: done with the permissions thanks a lot :) :) it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using custom modules, you can use Default Magento Backup.

Go to **System > Tools > backups** , than you create any kind of backup like

1)System Backup

2)Database Backup

3)Database & media Backup

once you click on "Roll back" it will revert backup to old state.

if the backup file didt created under **var** folder means, may be its **permission** issue.